# Missing TCL package smtp

Tags: scripting, smtp, tcl

I'm using activestate TCL which I thought was suppose to include smtp in the default install.

However when I run the following example (From the documentation):

```
proc send_simple_message {recipient email_server subject body} {
    package require smtp
    package require mime
    set token [mime::initialize -canonical text/plain \\
    -string $body]
    mime::setheader $token Subject $subject
    smtp::sendmessage $token \\
    -recipients $recipient -servers $email_server
    mime::finalize $token
}
send_simple_message someone@somewhere.com localhost \\
    "This is the subject." "This is the message."
```

I get the following error:

```
can't find package smtp
```

Is there something I have to do to enable the package in Activestate TCL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the smtp package from the ActiveState repository with `teacup` -

```
c:\> teacup install smtp
Resolving smtp ...   (etc)
```

Comment: Worked, but a script that works on the Mac OSX version of TCL doesn't on activestate still! :( It freezes at "Trying smtp.gmail.com..."